# cli C++ sort a objectlist on a certain property

Tags: sorting, object, c++-cli

I simply want to sort a list on a certain property.

I've got an `LinePiece`object with the following properties:

```
String^ Type;
int X, Y, X2, Y2;
System::String^ Text;
```

Now I have a list with these `LinePieces` and I want to sort them on the `X value`.

I found something in `List->Sort();` But I need to give some information. But I don't know how to tell it to sort my list on the X value.

So how can I sort my list on the X value of an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I read between the lines of your question, it sounds like sometimes you want to sort based on the `X` value, and sometimes you want to sort based on the `Y` value. If this is the case, then I'd implement a [Comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx) object, and pass that to [`List->Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx) to specify how they should be sorted.

```
public ref class CompareByX : Comparer<LinePiece^>
{
public:
    virtual int Compare(LinePiece^ a,LinePiece^ b) override
    {
        return a->X.CompareTo(b->X);
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    List<LinePiece^>^ list = ...

    list->Sort(gcnew CompareByX());
}
```

On the other hand, if `LinePiece` has a single, innate, universal sorting order, then I'd implement `IComparable` on the class, and use the default sorting. However, when you do this, you should be careful to only return `0` when the two objects are equal.

When you do this, you don't need to pass any extra parameters to [`Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx), since the objects already know how to sort themselves.

```
public ref class LinePiece : public IComparable<LinePiece^>
{
public:
    String^ Type;
    int X, Y, X2, Y2;
    String^ Text;

    virtual int CompareTo(LinePiece^ other)
    {
        int result = 0;

        if (result == 0) result = this->X.CompareTo(other->X);
        if (result == 0) result = this->Y.CompareTo(other->Y);
        if (result == 0) result = this->X2.CompareTo(other->X2);
        if (result == 0) result = this->Y2.CompareTo(other->Y2);
        if (result == 0) result = this->Type->CompareTo(other->Type);
        if (result == 0) result = this->Text->CompareTo(other->Text);

        return result;
    }
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    List<LinePiece^>^ list = ...

    list->Sort();
}
```

Comment: Well thats more complicated than the simple C# variant :P thanks for your help @David